# ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, linker-errors

I am trying to create a core data project in ios. But getting the error

ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

My header file looks like this -

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
  #import "ChoreMO+CoreDataClass.h"
  #import "PersonMO+CoreDataClass.h"
  #import "ChoreLogMO+CoreDataClass.h"

 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

 @property (readonly, strong) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;

  @property (readonly, strong) NSManagedObjectContext 
  *managedObjectContext;

 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

 @property (readonly, strong) NSPersistentContainer 
 *persistentContainer;

  - (void)saveContext;

  -(ChoreMO *)createChoreMO;

  -(PersonMO *)createPersonMO;

  -(ChoreLogMO *)createChoreLogMO;


  @end
```

I try to compile only this file and I am getting the linker error. I suspect something to do in this file itself.

Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Go to Xcode's Report Navigator, expand the line with the link error, and let us know which symbols it's finding as duplicates.

Comment: Another possibility: if you have codegen set to Class Definition for your entities but you also create explicit NSManagedObject subclasses, this can happen.  You need one or the other, not both.

Comment: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PersonMO in:
    /Users/sarahasif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataCourseEra-fqknjpjkyfofvzgwzogmhmbdysej/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataCourseEra.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreDataCourseEra.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PersonMO+CoreDataClass.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PersonMO in:
    /Users/sarahasif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataCourseEra-fqknjpjkyfofvzgwzogmhmbdysej/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataCourseEra.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreDataCourseEra.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PersonMO+CoreDataClass.o

Comment: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ChoreMO in:
    /Users/sarahasif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataCourseEra-fqknjpjkyfofvzgwzogmhmbdysej/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataCourseEra.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreDataCourseEra.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ChoreMO+CoreDataClass.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ChoreMO in:
    /Users/sarahasif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataCourseEra-fqknjpjkyfofvzgwzogmhmbdysej/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataCourseEra.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreDataCourseEra.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ChoreMO+CoreDataClass.o

Comment: ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64                                                  Above are the ^ duplicate symbols that i get error for.

Comment: The CodeGen did not create any NSManaged objcects. Since i needed to use those I created it explicitly in the AppDelegate.h file.

Comment: If you need to create them explicitly, switch codegen to Manual/None, clean the project, and rebuild.

Comment: Also you shouldn't need to import any of your own files from inside your own project. Just delete those lines.